# ASP Hidden Field - value does not update on server side after client side update

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using jQuery to implement a tab layout in an ASP.Net webpage.

There are elements on the page (eg. buttons) that raise server side events for processing. This processing and subsequent reloading of the page results in the tab state becoming 'corrupted' (the active tab changes back to the default). In an attempt to get around this, I have added an ASP Hidden Field element to the page and use it's value entity to keep track of the active tabs. When the value of the hidden field is changed, a server-side event is raised for the purposes of obtaining the new hidden field value and storing it as an object in the session.

**The problem:** When the tab is changed, the hidden field value updates correctly on the client, however, the event raised on the server does not change. Does anyone have a solution?

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            var selectedTab = document.getElementById('kLastTab').value;
            $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", selectedTab);
            document.getElementById('tabs').style.visibility = "visible";
        });

        $("#create").on("click", function () {
            document.getElementById('kLastTab').value = '0';
            __doPostBack('kLastTab', '');
            alert(document.getElementById('kLastTab').value)
            $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", $('tabs-1').index());
        });

        $("#manage").on("click", function () {
            document.getElementById('kLastTab').value = '1';
            __doPostBack('kLastTab', '');
            alert(document.getElementById('kLastTab').value)
            $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", $('tabs-2').index());

        });

    });


</script>
```

**ASP**

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
        <h2>Create, Close & Search Jobs.</h2>
    </hgroup>
    <article>
        <div id="tabs" style="visibility:hidden">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="create" href="#tabs-1">Create</a></li>
                <li><a id="manage" href="#tabs-2">Manage</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                ........
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="kLastTab" runat="server" Value="0" OnValueChanged="kLastTab_ValueChanged"/>
    </article>
</asp:Content>
```

Server-Side C# Value Changed Event

```
protected void kLastTab_ValueChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{            
    selectedTab = kLastTab.Value;
    Debug.WriteLine( "HiddenField Value = " + kLastTab.Value );
    Session.Add( "selectedTab", selectedTab );
}
```

**NOTE**

1. ClientIDMode is set to *Static*
2. The javascript alert confirms that the value of the hidden field is changed correctly on the client side.
3. The Debug.Writeline in value changed event shows that the hidden field value has not changed.

Comment: why don't you directly update the session from client side ?

Comment: So my understanding of this is that it can't be done using Javascript, more likely AJAX.

Comment: Have you tried using the inline server code `<%=kLastTab.ClientID %>`, pretty sure the client is going to send back the rendered control value instead of the server control.

Comment: Kramb - see note 1. ClientID is set to static, and just to ensure I wasn't being a goose. Yes I just changed it and this didn't help. Still, the clients value is updated, however the server does not.

Comment: Is there any way to update the rendered value from javascript?

Comment: Nalin - thanks for the recommendation, I looked into it. It is rather straight forward, and works. I am unsure if this solution presents other issues though.. Any comments?